Induction by Lorentz force
If the Lorentz force causes a charge separation in a conductor moving through a homogeneous magnetic field, why isn't a voltage induced when the measuring device moves along with the conductor? The magnetic flux doesn't change, but shouldn't the charge separation alone result in a measurable voltage?
What is the fundamental difference between a scenario where a conductor moves through a stationary magnetic field and one where both the conductor and the measuring device move? In both cases, the Lorentz force acts on the charges. However, why is a voltage only induced in the first scenario?

In the second scenario, the magnetic field will look like an electric field (transformation of EM fields between reference frames) which will cause the polarization, and the polarization will grow until the net force on a charge will be 0 (the polarization will cancel the electric field). If you're moving so fast that you see no magnetic field at all, then the force will be only due to the electric field, so the voltage will be 0

How does the measuring instrument move together with the conductor? A sketch or explanation would be good to understand the experimental setup.
